# Intellij IDEA Spring Boot configuration

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to import a Spring Boot project but when I am trying to Add New Configuration, it does not show a Spring Boot template.

Shall I do a configuration to the Intellij to enable Spring Boot projects?

I am using Intellij IDEA 2018.2 Ultimate edition (Evaluation version)

Comment: No, You don't need to do any configuration. Just import as `maven` or `gradle`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by using the following steps:
Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Spring Boot was not ticked by default

When I checked Spring Boot and pressed OK, it downloaded the relevant plugin. Then, in the Add New Configuration, a Spring Boot template appeared.

Comment: I dont see any plugin while I open my settings. Can you point here which plugin to download exactly.

Comment: Typically, you will not need it to do any configuration for Spring Boot in Intellij Idea. It works out of the box. My answer above related to an older version of Idea that I had. In any case, you can go to File->Settings->Plugins and search for Spring Boot. In my latest Idea, the plugin is by default enabled (bundled 202.7660.26). Which version of Idea you use? Mine is 2020.2.3 (Ultimate edition).